# Explanation of a sed command

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

I found this interesting command:

```
grep -v '^>' test.fasta | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

I have some grasp what it means (it counts letters from a text file), but my question is about this:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
```

I know that it is compose of three substitute commands. One is to substitute new lines (`\n`), one that matches any characters except newlines (`\(.\)`), but I am lost at `/\1\`?

Comment: It is fairly rough. The `tr` takes out all newlines, so the sed stdin is one long line (excluding the row headers, which start with `>`). Fasta files can be rather large (I see a topic in BioStars that quotes 54GB). `sed` is a line editor, so it reads the whole input into memory (as one line) before it processes it, at which point it doubles the size for the output (because every input char gets its own newline). A simple script (in Ruby or awk) would avoid six processes, five pipes, and two sorts (one of them with a line for every character).

Comment: Your `grep` flags exclude lines starting with `>`, correct? So this `grep `code excludes the first (descriptive ) line in a .fasta file, and (I presume), the rest of the code is designed to count occurrences of individual nucleotides (or amino acids).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command

```bsh
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
```

is a single GNU `sed` substitution command that replaces every character with itself, followed by a newline character. The effect of this is to fold the input into a single column of single characters.

```bsh
$ echo hello | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
h
e
l
l
o
```

The `\(.\)` is a "capture group", capturing a single character.  The `\1` is a "back-reference" to the first capture group.  Using `\1` in the replacement text would insert whatever was captured by the first parentheses.

It could also be written without so many backslashes as

```bsh
sed 's/./&\n/g'
```

where `&` simply means "whatever was matched by the expression".

The `sed` command requires GNU `sed` as standard `sed` can't insert newlines with `\n` like that.

To do that more efficiently with standard tools, use

```bsh
fold -w 1
```

instead.  This is more efficient as no regular expression matching is needed for each character in the input.

Using `fold`, your pipeline could be written

```
grep -v '^>' file | tr -d '\n' | fold -w 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Alternatively, using `awk` to get rid of a few steps of that pipeline,

```bsh
awk '!/^>/ { for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) count[substr($0,i,1)]++ }
    END { for (ch in count) print count[ch], ch }' file |
sort -rn
```

The `awk` code counts the number of times each character has been seen.  It does that by incrementing the value in the array `count` corresponding to each character in the input stream.  At the end of input, a summary of the counts and characters counted are outputted.

Comment: For _GNU_ awk 4.0 up you can eliminate the `sort -rn` by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"`

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl I saw your edit but rejected it. The `tr` command is still needed if the input contains two (or more) newlines in a row.

Answer (score 11):

I hope this makes it clearer.

> *"I know that it is compose of three substitute commands"*

It's just one substitute command (if you are referring to the `sed` command): `s/<pattern to search>/<replacement>/`, that will execute the following:

- For every line search for `<pattern>` and substitute it with `<replacement>`.
- The `g` flag means *do it **g**lobally*, because by default `sed` replaces only the first occurrence of `<pattern>`.

> *"but I am lost at `/\1\`"*

You can capture a pattern by surroundig it with escaped parenthesis `\(<pattern>\)`, or just parenthesis with the `-E` option, `(<pattern>)`.

In the `<replacement>` section this captured pattern is referenced by backslash and a number, `\<number>`. The number refers to the position of the capture, since you can have several:

```
sed -E '/(<first capture>)(<second capture>)/\1\2/'
```

So the command `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'` means:

- Capture every character `\(.\)` and replace it by itself and a new line `\1\n`.
- With `g`, do it globally, don't stop at the first occurrence.

For example:

```bsh
$ echo foo | sed -E 's/(.)/\1\n/g'
f
o
o
```

---

The `-e` options is not necessary here, unless you are concatenating several `sed` commands: `sed -e '...' -e '...'`, etc.

---

You can find more information at [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html).

Comment: Functionally what the replacement is doing is putting each character on its own line, finding a single character and replacing it with that character plus `\n`.

Comment: @JeffBreadner thanks, I'm still editing because I have power failures and I don't want to lose the changes.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'for lines.grep({ !/ ^ \> / }).join { .say for .comb.Bag.sort(*.values).reverse};'
```

Sample Input:

```
>sp|P01308|INS_HUMAN Insulin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=INS PE=1 SV=1
MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKTRREAED
LQVGQVELGGGPGAGSLQPLALEGSLQKRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN
```

Sample Output:

```
L => 20
G => 12
A => 10
E => 8
Q => 7
P => 6
C => 6
V => 6
R => 5
S => 5
Y => 4
F => 3
T => 3
N => 3
M => 2
D => 2
K => 2
I => 2
W => 2
H => 2
```

The code you present can be written in a number of languages (not only `sed`), any one of which may strike a chord with you. As an example, above your code has been re-written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of languages.

Most of the Raku code should be fairly self-explanatory: `lines` are read in, and `grep`-ped for the `!` absence of a `^` start-of-line `>` 'greater-than' angle, and `join`-ed. Joined lines are `comb`-ed (broken into individual characters), `Bag`-ged (each character present becomes a `key` and occurrences are counted/recorded as `values`), `sort`-ed in `reverse` to place highest # of occurrences first, then printed with `say`.

https://raku.org

Comment: I never heard about raku! Looks very nice indeed! 8)